# How to overlay shoreline shapefile into GeoTIFF file

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, shapefile

I have a shoreline shapefile of five great lakes and a georeferenced lakeshore TIFF photo of lake Ontario. I want to overlay the shoreline shapefile into tiff photo as a new raster layer. Specifically, I want to match pixels of shapefile and tiff photo with same coordinates. The result would be a m x n (dimension of one channel of TIFF photo) raster layer where values are 1 if the coordinate matches tiff file and 0 if not match. What should I do after read those files in as below? I can use basic GDAL, rasterio and GeoPandas in Python. I searched exsiting answers for a week but couldn't find one that matches my needs.

```
# read tiff file
ds = gdal.Open(path)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadAsArray()
# read shapefile
shoreline_delineation = gpd.read_file(shoreline_path)
```

Below are two images that I mentioned.

[image: georeferenced tiff file]

[image: Shapefile]

Comment: you need to change the projection of one or other of your datasets so it matches the other - do this by **reprojecting** the data set